# $20$ different comic books will be distributed to $5$ kids

Tags: combinatorics

> $20$ different comic books will be distributed to $5$ kids.
> (a) How many ways are there to distribute the comic books if there are **no restrictions** on how many go to each kid (other than the fact that all $20$ will be given out)?

I'm wondering if there's a generalization on this type of question. The answer is $5^{20}$ but at first, I was thinking $20^5$. What's the difference between these two representation?

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be $20 \times 19 \times 18 \times 17 \times 16$?

Answer (score 3):

The unifying principal with these "number of ways" problems is that you can arrive at a solution by clearly expressing what exactly constitutes a "way" and attempting to represent all the ways.
In this case it is intended that each book should go to exactly one child

So we can specify a way by saying which child each book goes to.

this can be done using a 20 element list for which the nth element is a number from 1 to 5 identifying the child who has book number $n$

e.g.     $$33333333333333333335   $$
would represent a way in which

- child #3 got books 1-19
- child #5 got book 20
- none of the other children got any books

since we have 20 numbers, each of which can take on values between 1 and 5, there must be $5^{20}$ possible ways.

If the question had been "How many ways all the children can choose their favourite of the 20 books, then we would be representing a way by specifying which of the 20 books went with which of the 5 children , That could be done with a 5 element list whose nth element is the number of child n's favourite book.
In that case, the number of ways would be $20^5$

Comment: The second part of my answer does begin with "if" - I was just trying to show what question might have the answer $20^5$. The actual question posed was "what is the difference between these two representations?"

Answer (score 0):

The way I like to think about these problems is to write five dashes, $$_ _ _ _ _ $$ and for each dash is a person. Without restrictions each person can receive all $20$ comics.

With most counting problems (ones I’ve experienced in discrete math) don’t usually have a underlying format. I like to list what I have and see if it matches the same format as old counting problems. The more you do, the more you’ll recognize. The reason to do each person is because we distribute the comics to the kids.